# How to avoid google indexing my site under development is completed

Tags: seo, meta-tags, robots.txt, googlebot, google-index

I have a new site and a new domain, will take about 2 months to complete development and then will go live. Only then I want google starts crawling and indexing my site.
So the question is how to "shut off" google indexing for these 2 months before going live?
Right now I plan to use this index.html:

```
<html>
<meta name="googlebot" content="noindex">
UNDER CONSTRUCTION
</html>
```

I will start development in index.php, when done I will remove index.html, then googlebot will start indexing starting from index.php.

Don't know if this sounds like a good plan.

Comment: You might want to google robots.txt files

Comment: Why not just password-protect your folder so nobody can access the site without the proper credentials? Web crawlers cannot access pw-protected pages either. Contact your hosting provider. Or just google *password protection with htaccess*.

Answer (score 0):

You can create robots.txt in your project directory and add following to it:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

So when a bot reaches your page it first checks robots.txt file and if disallow is there it would crawl your pages. Read more about it [here](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html)

Comment: Why was this downvoted? I use it and umm it  works for me ? Randomly downvoting answers without commenting wont help  anyone especially if answer is correct :/

Comment: robots.txt stops crawling, not indexing. The site could still be indexed. so this is not a solution.

Comment: Ok.. Try adding robots.txt with disallow and searching site:yourpage. It will throw a message saying robots.txt and wont index it.. Please get your concepts right :)

Comment: Also @user29671 can you please explain how would a page be indexed if it is not crawled?

Comment: Here is a resource for you all about robots.txt and direct to a relevant faq > https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/faq#h17

Comment: And here is a video form google which will help you understand how a page can be indexed, but not crawled https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KBdEwpRQRD0

Comment: And here is Google saying > 

..... If the page is blocked by a robots.txt file, the crawler will never see the noindex tag, and the page can still appear in search results, for example if other pages link to it.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710?hl=en

Blocking crawling does not block indexing.

Comment: Technically, if site is new and under construction the answer makes a lot of sense as there are no external links to the site.
Disallow in robots.txt: Blocking a page from being crawled will typically prevent pages from being indexed, as search engines are only able to index the pages they know about. While a page may be indexed due to links pointing to it from other pages, Google will aim to make the page less visible in search results.